# For loop through Array only shows last value, Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to place 3 markers on Google Map.

In JavaScript I wrote my loop as below

```
var places = ["Bondi Beach", "Coogee Beach", "Cronulla Beach"];
var lat = [-33.890542, -33.923036, -34.028249];
var lng = [151.274856, 151.259052, 151.157507];

var z=0;

for (tot=lat.length; z < tot; z++) {
  var locations = [
      [places[z], lat[z], lng[z]]
    ];
}
```

Then I initialized my map

```
var map;
var markers = [];

function init(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var num_markers = locations.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {  
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
      map: map,
      html: locations[i][0],
      id: i,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        id: this.id,
        content:this.html,
        position:this.getPosition()
      });
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function(){
        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
      });
      this.setVisible(false);
      infowindow.open(map);
    });
  }
}

init();
```

**However this output only one marker (the last one), I'm wondering what is wrong with my loop?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (tot=lat.length; z < tot; z++) {
  var locations = [
      [places[z], lat[z], lng[z]]
    ];
 }
```

Here you're overwriting the locations array with every iteration.
Push the new elements into the array instead.

```
var locations = []
for (tot=lat.length; z < tot; z++) {
   locations.push([places[z], lat[z], lng[z]]);
}
```

Comment: I believe var inside loop is a typo. :)

Comment: With the last edit now it works! Thank you all, I'm just starting to learn JS